# Unique solutions to infinite limits.

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits

Show that the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ tends to infinity is unique. We tried looking this question up already but there did not appear to be any online solutions.

Comment: What is the domain and codomain of $f$?

Comment: the domain is [a, infinity)

Comment: So the codomain is Hausdorff, this is the reason for [uniqueness of limit](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Convergent_Sequence_in_Hausdorff_Space_has_Unique_Limit).

Answer (score 1):

Saying that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)= L_1$ **means** "given any $\epsilon> 0$ there exist X such that if x> X then $|f(x)- L_1|< \epsilon$".   Saying that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)= L_2$ **means** "given any $\epsilon> 0$ there exist X such that if x> X then $|f(x)- L_2|< \epsilon$".  Choose $\epsilon$ to be smaller than $\frac{|L_1- L_2|}{2}$ and show that those cannot both be true.